# When is encoding being relevant in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, iso, utf

This might be a bit beginner question but it's fairly relevant considering debbuging encoding in Java: **At what point is an encoding being relevant to a String object?**

Consider I have a String object that I want to save to a file. Is the String object itself using some sort of encoding I should manipulate or this encoding will only be informed by me **when I create a stream of bytes to save**?

The same applies to importing: when I open a file and get it's bytes, I assume there's no encoding at hand, only bytes. When I parse this bytes to a String, I got to use an encoding to understand what characters are they. **After I parse those bytes**, the String (in memory) has some sort of meta information with the encoding or this is only being handled by the JVM?

This is vital considering I'm having file import/export issues and I got to understand at which point I should worry about getting the right encoding.

Hope I explained my doubt well, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Java strings do not have explicit encoding information.  All Java strings are UTF-16.  Period.  End-of-story.  Explicit encodings only come in to play when you create a new String from a given sequence of bytes, or when you convert a string _to_ a sequence of bytes.

Comment: ...which is why, to output Strings to files and such, you generally want a `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter`.  Note that several of their constructors take character set names.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you!About PrintStream and PrintWriter, there are constructor that **don't** take character set names. In this case, do you know where does the charset come from (OS, JVM...)?

Comment: Forgot to mention, on the input side, you want `InputStreamReader` which has constructors for charsets.

Comment: @gpaz In that case, the charset used is the OS default.  I forget which OS has which default, though.  Windows default is [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) AKA  ISO 8859-15 or something like that, I think.

Comment: @ABoschman Actually my main question is about in which **moment** the encoding I input is relevant, not actually the encoding being used in memory.

Comment: @Powerlord Thank you, that is a very important point regarding internationalization in my company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java strings do not have explicit encoding information.  They don't know where they came from, and they don't know where they are going.  All Java strings are stored internally as UTF-16.

You (optionally) specify what encoding to use whenever you want to turn a String into a sequence of bytes (e.g., to save to a file), or when you want to turn a sequence of bytes (e.g., read from a file) into a String.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding is important to String when you are de/serializing from disk or the web. There are multiple text file formats: ascii, latin-1, utf-8/16 (I believe there may be two utf-16 formats, but I'm not 100%)

See `InputStreamReader` for how to load a String from text encoded in a non-default format